# Cron Script to execute a job every 14 days from a given date in specific time zone

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I want to execute a Job in CRON for every 14 days from a specific date and timezone.

As an e.g. from JUNE 24TH every 14 days in CST time zone.

Comment: Please add more context and what have you tried so far

Comment: You can run one stored procedure to run every week and check the last run time June 24 should be equal to 14 days ahead to invoke your script otherwise skip that . Pseudo code  `if current_date == select dateadd (day , 14 , '24 june') invoke your script else skip`

Answer (score 0):

## Run job every fortnight

### The easy way

The easiest way to do this is simply to create the task to run every 14 days from when you want it to first run like:

```sql
CREATE TASK mytask_fortnightly
  WAREHOUSE = general
  SCHEDULE = '20160 MINUTE'
AS
  SELECT 'Hello world'
```

#### How it works

As there are 60 minutes in an hour, 24 hours in a day and 14 days in a fortnight, ergo that's 20,160 minutes.

#### Caveat

The above solution does not run the task every fortnight from a given date/time, but rather every fortnight from when the task is created.

Even though this is the simplest method, it does require you to be nominally present to create the task at the exact desired next scheduled time.

As a workaround however, you can create a one-shot task to do that for you the very first time at the exact correct date/time. This means you don't have to remember to be awake / alert / present to do it manually yourself, and you can clean up the creation task afterwards.

### The harder way.

Other solutions will require you to create a task which gets run every Thursday (since 2021-06-24 is/was a Thursday, each subsequent Thursday will either be the off-week, or the fortnight week)

e.g. `SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 0 0 * * THU'`

Then you will add specific logic to it to determine which one the correct fortnight is.

Using this method will also incur execution cost for the off-week as well to determine if it's the correct week.

#### Javascript SP

In javascript you can determine if it's the correct week or not by subtracting the start date from the current date and if it's not a mutiple of 14 days, use this as a conditional to short circuit the SP.

```js
const deltaMs = (new Date) - (new Date('2021-06-24'));
const deltaDays = ~~(deltaMs / 86400000);
const run = deltaDays % 14 === 0;
if (!run) return;

// ... continue to do what you want.
```

#### SQL

You can also check if it's a fortnight using the following SQL condition in a `WHERE` clause, or `IFF` / `CASE` functions.

```sql
DATEDIFF('day', '2021-06-24', CURRENT_DATE) % 14 = 0
```